# Wiring for outdoor sensor light

Tags: wiring, outdoor, light

I am trying to reconnect the wires for an outdoor sensor light (one sensor attached to two lights).

Where does the yellow wire go please?[image: please see attached image of wiring]

As per my reply to a comment further down in the discussion thread - here is a photo of another outdoor light that works fine (but also has more wires connected).

[image]

Many thanks

Comment: Note that there's bare wire sticking out of the brown insulation before it makes it into the white terminal block. That screw should be loosened and the wire pushed all the way in or trimmed shorter to ensure that all you can see is insulation, like in the blue wire connection next to it.

Comment: How could we possibly know? It's not like the wire colors inside motion sensor lights are standardized.  You would need to consult the manufacturer's schematic.  This is just a barf of random North American (black-white) and European (brown-blue) components.  I would spitball wild-guess that yellow is something different, like switched-hot (load) off the motion sensor? But I can't even see where that yellow wire goes. *GIGO, you're not helping us much here*.

Answer (score 2):

That's a complete mish-mash of wiring color schemes from two different continents in one fixture. Sometimes globalization really does things very poorly.

Presumably the Yellow (not being Brown or Blue, standard live & neutral for Europe and many other parts of the world) is **switched live** from the sensor, and would go to Black which is live (North American "hot" color code) to the sockets (which oddly looks to be crimped, so you'll need a new connector unless that's actually a weird looking wire-nut/Marrette, not a crimp) and the white wires which are neutral (North American color code) for the sockets would connect to incoming neutral (same situation with the apparent crimp.)

I find it odd that the yellow is not already connected to the blacks, and there's no sign of the wiring that would be required to accommodate the neutral connection if you are **reconnecting** this light fixture.

Comment: The mixed color schemes don't bother me, I think this answer is correct.  I think the yellow was torn out of the black crimp and as you say the whole thing will need replacing, and I think there was a white or blue, now missing, exactly as you say, also ripped out of the other crimp.  The bulbs are currently connected to each other and nothing else!

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help--much appreciated.

Comment: Many thanks for your kind help--much appreciated.

I agree, it all seems a bit odd (which is why I am asking for other opinions). There seems to be a fourth wire missing that comes out of the sensor. For reference, I am attaching a different photo that shows the wiring of one of my other outdoor lights (which works fine). 

The weird thing is that the sensor light which is causing me problems (the one in the first photo), was working fine with the same amount of wires. No wires have been added or removed. I just cannot remember how they were connected.